# get only the unmatched list as an output

Tags: text-processing, diff, comm

I want to know on which ports of firewalls from a particular customer the MAC Address Filtering is **not** active. So I have created 2 files:

- `all.txt` contains a list of all firewalls of a customer and looks like this:

  ```
  abc123 
  ahg578
  dfh879
  ert258
  fgh123
  huz546
  jki486
  lop784
  mnh323
  xsd451
  wqa512
  zas423
  ```
- `active.txt` contains a list of firewalls of the same customer in which the MAC Address filtering is active, and looks like this:

  ```
  abc123: set macaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00
  ahg578: set macaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00
  dfh879: set macaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00
  ert258: set macaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00
  fgh123: set macaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00
  huz546: set macaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00
  mnh323: set macaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00
  xsd451: set macaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00
  wqa512: set macaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00
  zas423: set macaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00
  ```

I have compared the two lists using

```
comm -3 ~/active.txt ~/all.txt
```

and get this result:

[image: result-list]

How can I get *only the unmatched list* as an output? So I want the output to be only

```
jki486
lop784
```

I have tried using `sdiff`, `grep -rL`, `grep -vxFf` but none of them works.

FYI, I'm using GNU. Linux version 3.2.0-6-amd64; gcc version 4.9.2

I would really appreciate your help! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

grep -v will work, just swap source with target. `-` will use pipe for `-f`
instead `-x` whole line `-w` whole word is recommended to ignore whitespaces from all.txt

```
cut -d\  -f1 active.txt | grep -vxFf - all.txt
```

Note the two whitespaces for cut: one escaped whitespace as delimiter

edit: if delimiter is a colon one must cut at `:` instead

```
cut -d: -f1 active.txt | grep -vwFf - all.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `awk`. The challenge in this case is that in `active.txt` the ports are immediately followed by a `:`, whereas in `all.txt` they stand isolated on the line. So you need to change the field separator in between:

```
awk -F':' 'FS==":"{ports[$1];next} !($1 in ports)' active.txt FS=" " all.txt
```

This will use the `:` as field separator while reading the list of active ports (i.e. processing the first file, `active.txt`), but set it to a space for processing the next file, `all.txt`.

- While processing `active.txt` (indicated by `FS`, the field separator, being equal to `:` as set via the `-F` option), we simply register the ports (i.e. the part *before* the first `:`) in an array `ports`. Execution then immediately skips to the next input line.
- While processing `all.txt` (`FS` is now a space, so the first action block is never entered), we simply check if the port is registered in the array `ports`. If it is not, the condition will evaluate to `true`, and the default action `print` will be invoked.

Comment: It works!!! Thank you so much @AdminBee :)
You're a hero!! :)

Comment: @EllaWidya You're welcome ;)